# Custom parameter in Auth->Login cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Can you pass an extra parameter in cakePHP on $this->Auth->Login

For example, I have a site table like the following;

```
 "Site"
  id
  name
```

I could have 40 sites and you should only be able to login to the site you are assigned too. You could also be a member of multiple sites. To define what site they are logging into i'm setting this on the login page.

```
 e.g. http://localhost/login/$id


 "Users"
  id
  username
  site_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify scope. Read the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) for details.

Comment: They ADmad, that makes perfect sense as I have used this in beforefilter:: to only allow activated users to login. Though i'm unsure on how to apply this for a variable being defined in the URL?